# How to use Jquery to re-format an html date output

Tags: jquery, date, content-management-system, format

I have a website outputting a date like the following....

```
<div class="day">Starting November 22 2014, 08:40 AM</div>
```

This page output can not be changed in the service, so I'm left using a client side method to modify it. Using jquery how can I go about parsing this to output as one of the following?

```
<div class="day">Nov 22nd, 8:40am</div>
<div class="day">11/22, 8:40am</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
function nth(d) {
    return ( [,'st','nd','rd'][/1?.$/.exec(d)] || 'th' );
}

function month(m) {
    return ['Jan','Feb','Mar','Apr','May','Jun','Jul','Aug','Sep','Oct','Nov','Dec'][m];
}

function time(d) {
  var hours = d.getHours();
  var minutes = d.getMinutes();
  var ampm = hours >= 12 ? 'pm' : 'am';
  hours = hours % 12;
  hours = hours ? hours : 12;
  minutes = minutes < 10 ? '0'+minutes : minutes;
  var strTime = hours + ':' + minutes + ' ' + ampm;
  return strTime;
}

var date = new Date($('.day').text()),
    d1   = month(date.getMonth()) + ' ' + date.getDate() + nth(date.getDate()) + ', ' + time(date),
    d2   = (date.getMonth() + 1) + '/' + date.getDate() + ', ' + time(date);
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/uPfE2/)

Answer (score 3):

<kbd>[**fiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/cse_tushar/F4c8z/)</kbd>

```
$('.day').text(function (_, txt) {
    d = new Date(txt.replace('Starting ', ''));
    return d.getMonth() + 1 + '/' + d.getDate() + ', ' + d.getHours() + ':' + d.getMinutes()+' '+txt.slice(-2);
});
```

---

Output

```
<div class="day">11/22, 8:40 AM</div>
```